# KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY vs KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY header on Spring Cloud

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud stream.
I was wondering what is the difference between `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY` and `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY`

I have 2 project, the first produce message using `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` as a header:

```
    public void sendResponse(ThirdPartyResponse thirdPartyResponse) {

        log.info("Sending response of type 'completed' [{}].", thirdPartyResponse);
        integrations.send(
                withPayload(ApplicationSubmissionSuccessPayload.success(thirdPartyResponse))
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, thirdPartyResponse.getData().getApplicationId())
                        .build());

    }
```

and the second one consume using `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY`

```
@StreamListener(target = "ofaOut")
public void receive(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String applicationId, @Payload String payload) throws JsonProcessingException {

...
}
```

however I got this error

```
    2020-03-23 16:13:27.924 ERROR 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : 
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'kafka_receivedMessageKey' for method parameter type [class java.lang.String], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[739],
 headers={kafka_offset=285, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@67c19b7c, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, 
kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, 
contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTopic=com.product.foo.ofa.out, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1584715870225, kafka_groupId=aop-foo-kyc}]
```

Its missing the header

```
Missing header 'kafka_receivedMessageKey'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RECEIVED...` is set on inbound messages; the other one is for the application to specify the key value for outbound messages.

They are different to avoid accidental propagation when an application receives a message does some work and re-publishes the message to, say, another topic.

When using Spring Integration, headers are automatically copied as a message traverses through the flow.

The outbound message mapper does not map the `RECEIVED...` headers so they don't appear in the `ProducerRecord`.

> `... kafka_receivedMessageKey=null ...`

Means the key was null on the inbound record.

To receive null keys, use

```
@Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = false)
```

Comment: So I should do ```.setHeader(KafkaHeaders. RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, thirdPartyResponse.getData().getApplicationId()) ``` in my producer project??

Comment: No; what you have is correct - it's just that you have a record in the topic with no key; to allow reception of such a message you need to add `required=false` to the annotation.

Comment: Got you but why I am send mesage with null key if I am doing ```.setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, thirdPartyResponse.getData().getApplicationId())```

Comment: Maybe an "old" record before you started setting the key? Or maybe `getApplicationId()` returned `null`? You can examine the records with the console consumer `$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic myTopic --from-beginning --property key.separator=: --property print.key=true`. It will print as `key:value`.